# No main manifest error when running spring boot microservice docker image

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, maven, microservices

I'm trying to dockerize a microservice I've build with SpringBoot and Maven, I can build the image properly but when trying to run it inside a docker container I get the following error:
[image]

I've read that this error has something to do with the spring-boot-maven-plugin, I've added it to my project main pom.xml file, but it still gives me the error (I've included a screenshot of the pom.xml at the end of this question).

This is my current Dockerfile:

[image]

Project structure:

[image]

Main pom.xml:

[image]

Comment: Add all information as text not ass image if possible

Comment: I can see your application is built uisng maven multi modules. Are you dockerizing parent app?

Comment: Ok @Jens, next time will do that.

Comment: @RohitAgarwal what do you mean when saying "dockerzing parent app"? As you can see in my project structure, my parent app doesn't exist, its only a maven module used to encapsulate the other ones.

Comment: Then this is your parent module only because it contains child as well. Can you please share main class?

Comment: As I said, my project contains multiple "main" classes, one for each module, do I have to specify a main class? How do I build a microservice then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've discovered that the problem wasn't with my project, but with the "target/" folder, which is generated by maven when running "mvn install", since I haven't cleaned my "target/" folder after my first install (which didn't had the spring-boot-maven-plugin), docker was using it to build my application, hence the "no main manifest" error. After running "mvn clean" and
"mvn install" for each module, docker was able to build and run both containers with no problem at all.